# ASP upload Exel file to the web error: The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

In my application, I try to upload the Excel data file to SQL database from the local machine to the web somee.com server. I tested it in local everything working fine. After I deployed application in server machine and tried to run then I got an error like "The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data”. I try to grant the NETWORK SERVICE account modify permission on my folder UploadExcel where my excel files will sit; unfortunately, it is not working.

ASPX.CS:

```
    static string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    public static string path = @"C:\UploadExcel\Sheet1.xls";
    public static string connStexcelConnectionStringr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtTime.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");                     
        string department_login = "";                                       
        bool check_login = authenticate.isAuthenticated();           

        if (check_login == false)
        {
            Response.Redirect("SPC_HP_trangdangnhap.aspx");
        }

        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            string username = Session["UserId"].ToString();                 
            department_login = authenticate.authenticateLogin(username);   

            if (!department_login.Equals("Kế toán"))
            {
                Response.Redirect("SPC_HP_trangdangnhap.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                BindGrid();
            }
        }
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        DateTime Day_Today = DateTime.Today;                  
        string today = Day_Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");        
        String strCmd = "";

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        strCmd += "SELECT ProductSPCCode, MaterialNameDB, ProductUnitStock, REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(Money, ProductTypeA),1),'.00','') AS ProductTypeA, REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(Money, ProductTypeB),1),'.00','') AS ProductTypeB ";
        strCmd += "FROM ProductStockTemp ";
        strCmd += "WHERE ProductStockTime = '"+ today + "'";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());
                grdProductStock.DataSource = ds;
                grdProductStock.DataBind();
                int column_count = grdProductStock.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
                grdProductStock.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
                grdProductStock.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                grdProductStock.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = column_count;
                grdProductStock.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "Chưa có tồn kho!";
            }
            else
            {
                grdProductStock.DataSource = ds;
                grdProductStock.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string excelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=YES;IMEX=1'", fupExcel.PostedFile.FileName);
        string timeJ = txtTime.Text;
        string time = DateTime.ParseExact(timeJ, "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd");
        DateTime.ParseExact(time, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime Day_Today = DateTime.Today;
        string today = Day_Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string file_Path = fupExcel.PostedFile.FileName;        
        string file_name = Path.GetFileName(file_Path);        
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(file_name);              
        string type = String.Empty;                             

        if (!fupExcel.HasFile)
        {
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Xin chọn file Excel!!!')</script>");
            return;
        }
        else
            if (fupExcel.HasFile)
            {
                switch (ext)    
                {
                    case ".xls":
                        type = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                        break;

                    /*case ".xlsx":
                        type = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                        break;*/
                }

                if (type != String.Empty)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                        {
                            using (SqlCommand cmd_delete = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM ProductStockTemp WHERE ProductStockTime = '"+ time +"'"))
                            {
                                cmd_delete.Connection = con;
                                con.Open();
                                cmd_delete.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                            con.Close();
                            con.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }

                    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connStexcelConnectionStringr))
                    {
                        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(("Select *,'" + time + "' as [productTime] FROM [Sheet1$]"), connection);
                        connection.Open();
                        using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(constr))
                            {
                                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "ProductStockTemp";

                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("productTime", "ProductStockTime");
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("MÃ HÀNG", "ProductSPCCode");
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("TÊN HÀNG", "MaterialNameDB");
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("ĐVT", "ProductUnitStock");
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("LOẠI A", "ProductTypeA");
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("LOẠI B", "ProductTypeB");

                                try
                                {
                                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                                    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Dữ liệu tồn kho Excel đã nhập vảo CSDL thành công!!!')</script>");
                                    BindGrid();
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    throw ex;
                                }
                                finally
                                {
                                    dr.Close();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Xin chọn file Excel có phần mở rộng .xls!!!')</script>");
                    return;
                }
            }
    }

    /* Method to exit */
    protected void imgExit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("KT_trangchu.aspx");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: okay i got your point.Just install AccessDatebaseEngine.exe on that server according to confgiuration i.e either x86 or x64.Here is the link to download that setup https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: I got the error message "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'" after I installed the x64 ADE you suggest.

Comment: Follow this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756759/the-microsoft-access-database-engine-could-not-find-the-object-sheet1   It might help you.